# Light syntax parser for Mathematica?

Tags: formatting, linux, character-encoding, parsing

My netbook is too slow to install Mathematica. I'm not set against working in a text editor, but I like having an automated highlighting/formatting environment; can anyone recommend a good gedit plugin or suggest an alternative solution?

To clarify: Unless there's something amazing online that can act as a virtual back-end using my login info, I can't use a front-end.

Comment: There's this for textmate on macs https://github.com/shadanan/mathematica-tmbundle... There might be some editors on ubuntu that can interpret textmate config files

Comment: Sublime Text can use textmate plugins, and is cross-platform. It is not free, but has no limit on the trial period: http://www.sublimetext.com/ .

Comment: Vim comes with a syntax highlighter for Mathematica.  It's rather old though and you'll have to set it up to associate `.m` files with Mathematica (and not MATLAB or something else).

Comment: @Malte have you actually used that bundle? It appears to not display symbols in the symbol list (either in textmate or ST). I fixed it for my own use but if other people also use it I could clean it up and make it available.

Comment: @acl post that in a meta post! I'm sure it will be useful for a few users.

Comment: I like sublime, it would be great if someone could confirm whether the mac bundle works!

Comment: @acl I've been giving sublime a try and it looks nice (it even has decent vim commands and modal editing support out of the box). Please post the fixed version so that I can give it a try. You can post here in your answer too, I suppose.

Comment: @rm-rf it's a bit longer than that. the reason I am hesitating is that it will take some time to clean the thing up, make sure it's correct etc. I just modified a few regexps and did not check carefully what it broke. I'll try to do that over the weekend.

Comment: @acl Still interested in that bundle!

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK with using emacs, there's a [mode](http://www.watson.org/~mccann/mathematica.el) which allows it to act as a front-end. There are also modes for editing m-files, eg [this](http://chasen.org/~daiti-m/dist/math++.el).

Comment: The second link looks promising, can you tell me how I would integrate it into emacs? There are instructions only for the front-end mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a more powerful box available, you could install Mathematica there, and run it from the netbook using X forwarding over SSH ([`ssh -X`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/ssh.1.html)). The UI should be responsive as long as you have a good network connection and you aren't displaying large graphics or plots.

Some documentation for setting up an SSH server:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Secure_Shell&oldid=257636#X11_forwarding
- https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH

Comment: I would recommend [nx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology) as it has much better performance, especially with a slow connection!

Comment: You probably want to mention the possibility to do the same in a platform independent way using VNC. That can also be somewhat simpler to setup and in my experience often gives better performance -- all depending on the details of the connection between the two computers (I have no experience in how it compares to sebhofers suggestion to use nx). Also a VNC session will survive an interrupted connection, while I remember X programs don't like such interrupts.